# error while installing windows 7 through virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, bios, error-handling

[image]i have installed the extention packs of virtualbox a few monent ago and and again i click the button to install it it shows an other error related to BIOS [image]

currently i am using an integrated motherboard of gigabyte company is there any solution for this issue

i have vt-x amd amd-v enabled

Comment: no i have hardware virtualisation technology enabled in my system

Comment: can you solve this problem for me

Comment: this is not about ubuntu in any way, maybe should be migrated to superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following command as root to verify that host cpu has support for AMD - V technology:

```
# grep --color svm /proc/cpuinfo
```

If the output has the svm flags, then AMD CPU host is capable of running hardware virtualization.
Then check in your system BIOS if the virtualization is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your system does not support AMD-V. So that unchecked Enabled VT-x/AMD-V.

[image]

You got your problem resolved.